# Python pandas loop value conditional on two columns

Tags: python, function, loops, pandas

In my dataframe 'data' I have two columns 'trend' & 'rtrend'

`trend` has values -1, 0 and 1.

```
def newfunc(a):

j = -1

for i in a:

    j = j+1
    x = (j-1)

    if data.iloc[j]['trend'] != 0:

        return data.iloc[j]['trend'] 

    if data.iloc[j]['trend'] == 0:

        return data.iloc[x]['rtrend']
```

If `trend` is equal to -1 or 1 then I'd like to set the `rtrend` column value equal to `trend`.

If `trend` equals 0, then set `rtrend` equal to the last value in that series which appears above in the dataframe.

```
data['rtrend'] = newfunc(data['trend'])
```

All it currently returns is 0 for the whole series.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?  I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. (I've tried `np.where()` which doesn't seem to do what I'm after).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do a procedural slow `for` loop. Do the vectorized approach. Just copy non zero data into your new `rtrend` column, then forward fill the data:

```
df['rtrend'] = df[df.trend!=0]['trend']

df
Out[21]: 
   trend    b    c  rtrend
a   -1.0  1.0 -1.0    -1.0
c    0.0 -1.0  1.0     NaN
e    1.0 -1.0 -1.0     1.0
f   -1.0  1.0 -1.0    -1.0
h   -1.0  1.0  1.0    -1.0

df['rtrend'].ffill()
Out[22]: 
a   -1.0
c   -1.0
e    1.0
f   -1.0
h   -1.0
Name: rtrend, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @piRSquared :-) Thanks!

Comment: You should use `.loc` whenever possible to avoid the setingwithcopy warning. `df.loc[df.trend != 0, 'trend']`

Comment: @TedPetrou hmm no because in this case I'm not dealing with a left-assignment value, the dataframe view I'm doing is the right side of the assignment (the left side being the new column `rtrend`)

Comment: @Boud Thanks, this would fix the problem although for some reason I can't get  the last part to work. 'data['rtrend'].ffill()'   to work. It doesn't return any errors but 'NaN' still exists in the code and appears to not have done anything. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Amend your question with a sample dump of your df to illustrate your issue

Comment: I managed to use `data.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)` which worked on the dataframe.  the `'ffill()' method I could only get to work if I selected a smaller slice for some reason. (must have been me doing something wrong).  Thanks